# Not able to write 'Nan' in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, pandas, elasticsearch, null, kibana

I am creating pandas dataset with such that 'num_specimen_seen' is having one value null. I am defining nan using the math.nan. The dataset df is saved in haze.csv file.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2,math.nan, 8]},
                  )
df.to_csv('haze.csv')
Unnamed: 0  num_legs    num_wings   num_specimen_seen
0   0   2   2   10.0
1   1   4   0   2.0
2   2   8   0   NaN
3   3   0   0   8.0
```

I am uploading this haze.csv to Elasticsearch using eland as follows:

```
ed.csv_to_eland(
...      "haze.csv",
...      es_client='http://localhost:9200',
...      es_dest_index='haze',
...      es_refresh=True,
...      index_col=0
... )
```

But it is giving an error as follows:

BulkIndexError: 1 document(s) failed to index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [index pandas dataframe in elasticsearch with null values but no nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59806405/index-pandas-dataframe-in-elasticsearch-with-null-values-but-no-nan)